# calculus - Finding the potential of this differential form

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$\omega(x, y) = (e^{x+y}cos(x))dx+\frac{1}{2}(e^{x+y}(cos(x)+sin(x))dy $

I need to find the potential of $ \omega(x, y)$ so I integrate $ e^{x+y}cos(x))dx $ because it looks like the easiest to integrate.

Integrating by parts twice, I get that $\int e^{x+y}cos(x) dx = \frac{1}{2}e^{x+y}(cos(x)+sin(x)) + c $

Is $\frac{1}{2}e^{x+y}(cos(x)+sin(x)) + c $ the potential of this differential form?

Comment: Check your own work: what’s the exterior derivative of the function that you’ve computed?

Comment: Should I calculate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{1}{2}e^{x+y}(cos(x)+sin(x)) ? $ Because if so I get the same function as a result. Not sure what to do next, though

Comment: Well, $df = f_x\,dx+f_y\,dy$. Does $f_y$ match the coefficient of $dy$ in $\omega$?

Comment: Mmh, I think it does? Sorry but I'm slightly confused.